# How can you search through records to find one by name or partial name? C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, search

I have a program with a structure as follows:

```
struct FundData
{
    char fundName[SIZE]; //Fund Name
    char fundInception[SIZE]; //Fund inception date
    double ytd; //Year to date return as percent
    double oneYear; //1 year Return as percent
    double threeYear; //3 year Return as percent
    double fiveYear; //5 year Return as percent
    double tenYear; //10 year Return as percent
    double fundExpense; //Fund Yearly Expense as percent
};

FundData newData[5];
```

I use a menu to add records of the stucture to a file, display all records, and now I'm having trouble deleting a record. I can't figure out how to search for the record using either a full name or partial name. I tried using seekg but it won't let me search by a char array. I need to search for the fund by whole or partial fund name, display the data for that fund, then prompt the user to confirm deletion. However I'm stuck on the first part, finding the record.

Comment: At first, try not to use arrays in C++, if it is fixed length try to use `std::array`, and if it is variable length try to use `std::vector`, while using C-style arrays and pointers are a door for a lot of bugs. Second: The easiest way is using the `algorithms` library in the C++ standard library, you can use `find_if`, or you can iterate normally through the array using a for loop. For searching for a partial string, you can use `std::search`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search

Comment: I'm a pretty basic intro class so unfortunately we haven't done any of that yet. They gave us the structure to use, but I can't seem to search through the file; I could search through a basic array but the file is throwing me off.

Comment: Since it looks like you are being forced to use character arrays for strings, [you may find `strncmp` helpful](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp). It will compare up to the first N characters of arrays 1 and 2 and return true if they match. See the linked documentation page for examples.

Comment: On second thought, that's only helpful if the partial name must be at the beginning of the full name. If you want to find "don" in "McDonalds", you'll have to work a bit harder. For one thing, you'll want to convert everything to a to a common case otherwise "don" won't match "Don"

Comment: @computerilliterate -- *I need to search for the fund by whole or partial fund name, display the data for that fund, then prompt the user to confirm deletion* -- What if more than one name matches the partial search?   The "real world" way to do these partial searches is to build a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) consisting of the fund names (read the **Dictionary representation** section at the link).

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to do that using raw arrays only.

The standard library contains all sorts of algorithm that work of a plenty of use cases. One of the provided algorithm is exactly the one you're looking for: `std::find_if`!

It is used like this:

```
// put that include in the top of the file
#include <algorithm>

auto the_one_to_find = "name to find";

auto found_element = std::find_if(
    std::begin(newData), std::end(newData),
    [&](const FundData& data) {
        return std::strncmp(data.fundName, the_one_to_find, SIZE);
    }
);

// if the fund has been found
if (found_element != std::end(newData)) {
    std::cout << found_element->fundName; // found it!
}
```

You must have C++14 to use `std::begin` and `std::end`, it's available on all recent compiler and often enabled by default.

Comment: Also `std::strcmp` can be replaced by `std::search` using `std::begin` and `std::end` of the strings themselves, at least use `strncmp` because it may cause a vulnerability if the strings are not correctly null terminated

Answer (score 1):

The function template `find_name()` below performs linear search ([`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)) on the passed `FundData` array for finding an element with the string `name` as `fundName`. It uses [`std::strncmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncmp) for comparing the strings instead of `std::strcmp`. `array_len()` is just a convenience function template for inferring the size of a built-in array (used for the array data member `fundName`).

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t array_len(T(&arr)[N]) {
   return N;
}

template<size_t N>
FundData* find_name(FundData (&arr)[N], std::string name) {   
   auto pred = [&name](const FundData& data) {
      return !std::strncmp(data.fundName, name.c_str(), array_len(data.fundName));
   };

   auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), pred);

   if (std::end(arr) == it)
      return nullptr;

   return &*it;
}
```

Then, you can use it this way:

```
auto main() -> int {
   FundData newData[5];

   // ...

   auto ptr = find_name(newData, "FooBar");

   if (ptr)
      std::cout << ptr->fundName << '\n';
}
```